# Delay showing widget (listview) flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, delay

I've a list view that is retrieved from the firebase but it takes sometime before it showed so it gives null error before showing it, I think the solution is to give the list view a delay before showing it but I didn't know how since the Future.delay is not a widget I cannot give it to a child.

this is my code.

```
Widget DrawerList() {
return BlocConsumer<UserCubit, UserState>(listener: (context, state) {
  
}, builder: (context, state) {
  return Container(
    width: 300,
    height: 250,
    child: Scrollbar(
      thumbVisibility: true,
      child: /////////////I tried to put futuer.delay here since this is the list view i want to show after seconds
      ListView.separated(
        ...........
  );
});
```

}

Comment: show a loading indicator when your state is loading and show the listview when state is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

In cubit:

```
fetchData(){
emit(Loading());

//fetching data code here if success, emit success state and if else, emit error


}
```

In view :

```
    Widget DrawerList() {
return BlocConsumer<UserCubit, UserState>(listener: (context, state) {
  
}, builder: (context, state) {
  return Container(
    width: 300,
    height: 250,
    child: Scrollbar(
      thumbVisibility: true,
      child: state is Loading?Text("Loading ..."):
      state is Error?Text("Oops, error")
      :ListView.separated(
        ...........
  );
});
```